# Strange C++ Arduino serial behavior

Tags: c++, arrays, arduino

I am writing some code for my arduino to print 4 button states and the X,Y coordinates from an analogue joystick and I am having strange behavior.

Here is the code:

```
  int x,y;
  x = analogRead(joy_x);
  y = analogRead(joy_y);
  char* buf = new char[4];
  sprintf(buf, "%4d", x);
  Serial.print("X:");
  Serial.print(buf);
  Serial.print(" Y:");
  sprintf(buf, "%4d", y);
  Serial.println(buf);

  int one,two,three,four;
  one = digitalRead(touchOne);
  two = digitalRead(touchTwo);
  three = digitalRead(touchThree);
  four = digitalRead(touchFour);

  // create an array of states set to the default values
  char states[4] = {'X', 'X', 'X', 'X'};
  // change each value if it is not in the default state
  if(one   == 1) states[0] = 'O';
  if(two   == 1) states[1] = 'O';
  if(three == 1) states[2] = 'O';
  if(four  == 1) states[3] = 'O';
  // output the states to the OLED display
  //display.print(states);
  Serial.print(states);
```

When it is run the serial output looks like this:

```
XXXX3X: 515 Y: 520
XXXX3X: 516 Y: 520
XXXX3X: 516 Y: 519
XXXX3X: 516 Y: 520
XXXX3X: 515 Y: 520
XXXX3X: 516 Y: 519
XXXX3X: 516 Y: 520
XXXX3X: 515 Y: 519
XXXX3X: 516 Y: 520
```

Even though the X, Y should be before the XXXX and the number three appears from nowhere.
I hope this mystery can be solved, thanks.

Comment: Not tested, changing `char states[4] = {'X', 'X', 'X', 'X'};` to `char states[5] = {'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', '\0'};` (adding terminating null character) may work. Also, change `new char[4]` to `new char[5];` because 4 byte is too small to store the result of `sprintf` and it causes buffer overrun which is considered as dangerous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several buffer overruns in the code.

```
  char* buf = new char[4];
  sprintf(buf, "%4d", x);
  ...
  sprintf(buf, "%4d", y);
```

This needs room for the null terminator which `sprintf` adds.

```
  char* buf = new char[5];
```

Also easier: there's no need to use the free store here.

```
  char buf[5];
```

Same kind of thing here:

```
  char states[4] = {'X', 'X', 'X', 'X'};
  ...
  Serial.print(states);
```

We need to add a null terminator to make it a valid string.

```
  char states[5] = {'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', '\0'};
```

That should take care of the immediate memory issues.

Comment: Hi, I did this but now there are 5 'X's in the output

Comment: I think that should be "normal" based on what you are doing, since you have, at the beginning, `Serial.print("X:")`. The other 4 Xs you might get from `states`. I'm not sure exactly what you want there.

Comment: But why are the x's coming out before the joysick values?

Comment: I'm afraid that I can't answer based on the code provided -- because I don't know what this `Serial.print` and `Serial.println` does exactly. These memory access issues above are definitely a problem though.

Comment: I was looking through this Arduino interface documentation trying to figure out what's up. It might help to `sprintf` everything you want into a big buffer (ex: `char buf[256]`), then just call `Serial.println` at the very end. That should give you back a more predictable output order. There might be some funky thing going on with flushing that's giving that funny order.

Comment: A little bit intrusive, but if you're using C++, then I/O streams might be easier (`std::stringstream`, e.g.) . You don't have to worry about buffer overruns and things like that -- but probably more immediate is just `sprintf` to a big buffer and use `Serial.println` at the end.

Comment: Ok, I'll give that a go. Thanks.